# Passing custom arguments into rails console (2.2.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, console

I have a rails 2.2.2 app.  I'd like to be able to start the console by passing in a custom variable, which i can then retrieve inside my environment.  Something like

```
#i start console like so
rails/console production -uid 1182
```

Then, **anywhere** in my code, i would be able to access this "uid" variable in the same sort of way that i can access ENV['HOME'] or things like that.  (it doesn't need to be in ENV, just so long as i can access it reliably).

Anyone know how i can do this?  thanks, max

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
uid=1182 rails/console production
```

This way you set env variable, accessible from Ruby with:

```
ENV['uid']
```

Comment: that works! thanks - i wouldn't have thought of doing it in front of the command instead of after :) I notice it only works when i do it as the same command:  this, for example, DOESN'T work: `uid=1182; script/console production`.  Mind explaining the difference here?  thanks!

Comment: @MaxWilliams frankly, I don't know (I'm not shell expert, unfortunately). But I think you'll find all the info you want [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-variables/).

Comment: indeed - thanks: here's the answer: " You need to export the variable for it to be inherited by another program".  This DOES work: `export uid=1182; script/console production`.  Cheers!